# Having zero rows at specific positions in array in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have an array `A`. I am printing a new array `result` by considering specific locations according to list `J`. However, I want to insert element `0` for all other positions. For example, I want to insert `0` at `[0,2,3]` locations of `result` since these are not included in `J`. I show the current and expected outputs.

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],
            [6,7,8,9,10],
            [11,12,13,14,15],
            [16,17,18,19,20],
            [21,22,23,24,25]])


J=[[1, 4]]
result=np.array([list(A[i]) for i in J[0]])
print([result])
```

The current output is

```
[array([[ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]])]
```

The expected output is

```
[array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]])]
```

Comment: Your expected output is not a valid numpy array. All "*columns*" should have the same number of items.

Comment: I have corrected.

Comment: Ok, see answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
out = np.zeros_like(A)
out[J[0]] = A[J[0]]
```

Output:

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]])
```

Or if you want to modify `A` in place:

```
A[~np.isin(np.arange(A.shape[0]), J[0])] = 0
```